# What is the best way to create a unique array of values from a string?

Tags: perl

Is there a nice one liner in perl that lets you create an array of unique values from a string?

```
$str = "bob-2-4 asdfasdfasdf bob-2-4 asdfasdf bob-3-1";
my @unique = $str =~ m/(bob-\d-\d)/g;
# array is now "bob-2-4, bob-2-4, bob-3-1"
```

I want the unique array to only contain "bob-2-4, bob-3-1" however.

Comment: `perl -E 'say for grep { /^bob-\d+-\d+$/ && !$s{$_}++ } split " ", shift' 'bob-2-4 asdfasdfasdf bob-2-4 asdfasdf bob-3-1'`

Comment: Or if you want an array (not a one-liner) then `my %s; my @unique = grep { /^bob-\d+-\d+$/ && !%s{$_}++ } split ' ', $str;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're talking about uniques, the tool for the job is a hash.

You can do:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;

my $str = "bob-2-4 asdfasdfasdf bob-2-4 asdfasdf bob-3-1";
my %unique = map { $_ => 1 } $str =~ m/(bob-\d-\d)/g;
print keys %unique;
```

As a one liner, straight into your array, you could:

```
my @unique = keys %{{map { $_ => 1 } $str =~ m/(bob-\d-\d)/g}};
```

This does approximately the same thing - use `map` to construct the hash, and then `keys` to extract the unique values. Note - `keys` doesn't return a defined order.

If ordering is important, you could also use `grep`, but you'll still need a hash:

```
my $str = "bob-2-4 asdfasdfasdf bob-2-4 asdfasdf bob-3-1";
my %seen;
my @unique = grep { not $seen{$_}++ } $str =~ m/(bob-\d-\d)/g;
print @unique;
```

Comment: You could also use `uniq` from List::MoreUtils, which does the same thing, but is syntactically cleaner.

Comment: Don't see the point of using the solutions that don't preserve the order, especially since they create a copy of all the unique values for nothing.

Answer (score 5):

Without modules:

```
sub uniq { my %seen; grep !$seen{$_}++, @_ }
```

With a commonly-used module:

```
use List::MoreUtils qw( uniq );
```

Usage:

```
my $str = "bob-2-4 asdfasdfasdf bob-2-4 asdfasdf bob-3-1";
my @unique = uniq $str =~ m/(bob-\d-\d)/g;
say for @unique;
```